# How do I debug Node back end in production?

Tags: node.js, logging

We're a small startup running Node for our backend. Using a combination of LogDNA, FullStory, Sentry and Mixpanel across frontend and backend.
Problems I face:

1. Can't trace user journey: User reports a bug. I look through logs with a timestamp of the user report, but can't trace the user journey, especially with lots of asynchronous operations going on in parallel
2. Insufficient logging: I can identify the error being thrown but can't identify the cause. Would want to see logs of surrounding code which we maybe didn't log

To solve this, I've resorted to adding logging around the suspected problem path, pushing to production and asking the user to try again (very annoying for them)

Any best practices I'm missing or is this really the best way to be debugging issues in prod?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack, there are existing integrations that might just do what you are looking for!
To understand user journey and help with debugging:

- Use Sentry+FullStory to make sure every error in Sentry is paired with a FullStory session link and Sentry errors are searchable in FullStory.
- Add FullStory Session URL to every Mixpanel event.
- A step further: add helpdesk system integration to have FullStory session link to your support ticket (see below for supported partners)

With these you can navigate directly from an error to the user replay session and vise versa, follow the user journey to see and replicate the issue they are facing, search for certain errors in FullStory to see how many users/sessions affected, view breadcrumbs that lead to the error, etc.

Watch this Webinar to understand how they work together: https://www.fullstory.com/resources/debugging-with-sentry-fullstory/

here are some more information:

Integrations:

https://partners.fullstory.com/integrations/solution/792/mixpanel

https://partners.fullstory.com/integrations/solution/780/sentry

https://partners.fullstory.com/integrations/ in "Customer Success Platform" section, see if your helpdesk system is supported.

Dev tools in FullStory: https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020828313-Guide-to-Dev-Tools

React and Redux w/ Sentry + Fullstory: https://bionic.fullstory.com/react-redux-errors-with-fullstory-and-sentry/